# How can I combine these two strings using VBA while keeping the fonts and colors the same?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm trying to keep the characteristics of the two texts the same. All I want to do is take the text from column A, row 1 and make sure it's repeated in column B, row 1. If it is, I don't have to do anything. If it isn't, then all I would need to do is take the text from first first box, strike it through, make it red, and add it to the text in box 2.

How would I be able to do that? I tried assigning the text as a string to a variable, but when I try to combine it, the all the colors turn to black. Is there any simple approach to this?

[Inputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gsbbV.png)
[Desired Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYwZ3.png)

I'm fairly new to VBA and any help would be greatly appreciated!

As for my code, this is what I have so far, but I think I'll have to completely rewrite it.

```
       x = Cells(i, 1) & "" & " "
    w = Cells(i, 2)
    If InStr(LCase(Cells(i, 2)), LCase(x)) = 0 Then
        full = x & "" & w
        Cells(i, 2) = full
    End If
    For lcounter = 1 To Len(Cells(i, 1))
        If Cells(i, 1).Characters(lcounter, 1).Text = Cells(i, 2).Characters(lcounter, 1).Text And Cells(i, 2).Characters(lcounter, 1).Font.ColorIndex = 3 Then
            Cells(i, 2).Characters(lcounter, 1).Font.Strikethrough = True
            Cells(i, 2).Characters(lcounter, 1).Font.ColorIndex = 3
        End If
    Next lcounter
```

This code only works if all of the text in cell 2 is red before merging. For some reason, if that's the case, the combined text is also red.
But otherwise, for the example in the picture, this code doesn't work.

Comment: Please share the code you've got as text so we can build on it. You can [edit your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72454888/edit) at any time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Format Characters

```vb
Sub FormatCharacters()

    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ws.Range("A1:B1")

    Dim Cell1 As Range: Set Cell1 = rg.Cells(1)
    Dim Cell2 As Range: Set Cell2 = rg.Cells(2)
        
    If Cell1.Value <> Cell2.Value Then
                
        ' Write the formats of the 2nd cell to an array.
        
        Dim Len1 As Long: Len1 = Len(Cell1)
        Dim Len2 As Long: Len2 = Len(Cell2)
    
        Dim LB As Long: LB = Len1 + 2
        Dim UB As Long: UB = LB + Len2 - 1
        
        Dim arr2() As Variant: ReDim arr2(LB To UB, 1 To 2)
        Dim j As Long: j = LB
        
        Dim i As Long
                
        For i = 1 To Len2
            With Cell2.Characters(i, 1).Font
                arr2(j, 1) = .Color
                arr2(j, 2) = .Strikethrough
                j = j + 1
            End With
        Next i
    
        ' Concatenate the strings.
        
        Cell2.Value = Cell1.Value & " " & Cell2.Value
        
        ' Format the 1st cell's string.
        
        With Cell2.Characters(1, Len1).Font
            .Color = vbRed
            .Strikethrough = True
        End With
        
        ' Format the 2nd cell's string.
        
        For j = LB To UB
            With Cell2.Characters(j, 1).Font
                .Color = arr2(j, 1)
                .Strikethrough = arr2(j, 2)
            End With
        Next j
                
    End If
            
End Sub
```